Data Source Not Visible in SSRS Report Manager
We generated SSRS reports a year ago, and now we need to create new reports. However, the data sources we created are not visible on the report server.
We can go to Report Manager and navigate to the report that we want, then go to the Manage section. However, when we do this, we are unable to see the details of the data source or connection string. Specifically, We need information about which databases and tables these reports are generated from, or the connection string itself.
All we see in the Manage section is:


Is there any way to view those data sources on the report server?
Additionally, what alternative solutions are available if we cannot see the data sources?

This issue has been resolved. We had to log in to the VM using admin credentials, and only then could we see the DATA SOURCE on the report server.

The issue was identified as a permissions problem. We had logged in using credentials that did not have full permissions assigned. The problem has since been resolved by using the correct credentials with the necessary permissions.
